# Create jstree with json data from different table

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I want to create a jstree with data from different tables for example the data from table 1 will be the parent node and the data from the table 2 will be the children. I googled for answers and tutorials but it only give me demos that only have one table. I am using also codeigniter by the way. Here is my attempt:

my controller function

```
public function loadFabricTree()
{
    $data['fabric'] = $this->ModelDB->getFabricType();
    $data['design'] = $this->ModelDB->getdesign();
    $fabrics = array();
    $children1 = array();

    foreach($data['design'] as $val)
    {
        $children[] = ['id'=>$val['id','text'=>$val['Design']]];
    }

    foreach($data['fabric'] as $val)
    {           
        $fabrics[] = ['id'=>$val['id'],'parent'=>"#",'text'=>$val['ItemDesc']]; // I tried to add 'children'=>$children1
    }

    echo json_encode($fabrics);
}
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#FabricTree').jstree({
    'plugins': ['wholerow', 'checkbox'],
    'core': {
      'data': {
        'url': '/mps/index.php/mps/loadFabricTree',
        'dataType': 'json'
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Whenever i try to add the **$children** variable in the **$fabrics**, the tree only continues to load but no data is generated.

Comment: Whats your desire output results please ?

Comment: The desire output is that every parent node of fabric should have the same children of design.

Comment: Can you write sample json data which you want as output please ?